# By re-opening script, processing speed decreases

Tags: performance, python-2.7, slowdown

This is the code I have written.
It parses an xml and turns on lights when a certain condition is true.
The problem I have is, if I restart the script it takes longer to read out or process the xml. If I restart again, it takes even longer. So at some point it takes 10 or more seconds till one cycle is through.

```
def core():

    import urllib                                                               #import urllib.request

    x = 0

    while True:

        ### XML Extraction ###
        from xml.dom import minidom

        xml = urllib.urlopen("http://192.168.60.242/xml")                       # xml = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.60.242/xml")
        xml_string = xml.read()
        xml.close()

        re_string = xml_string[130:4000]
        re_string = re_string.replace('</TEXTAREA></FORM></BODY></HTML>', '')   #zwecks inkompatibilitÃ¤t mit Python 3.5, muss hier eine Ã„nderung vorgenommen werden

        #parsing
        xmldoc = minidom.parseString(re_string)


        Sensor0Elm = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('t0')                                  
        Sensor1Elm = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('t1')
        #Sensor2Elm = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('t2') 

        Sensor0Elm = Sensor0Elm[0]
        Sensor1Elm = Sensor1Elm[0]
        #Sensor2Elm = Sensor2Elm[0]

        Sensor0 = Sensor0Elm.childNodes[0].data
        Sensor1 = Sensor1Elm.childNodes[0].data
        #Sensor2 = Sensor2Elm.childNodes[0].data 


        Sensor0 = float(Sensor0)
        Sensor1 = float(Sensor1)
        #Sensor2 = float(Sensor2)


        #Datenaufbereitung
        print (Sensor0*100.000000000001)
        print (Sensor1*100.000000000001)
        #print (Sensor2*100)


        ### int to bin ###
        Sensor0=bin(int(Sensor0*100.000000000001))
        Sensor1=bin(int(Sensor1*100.000000000001))
        #Sensor2=bin(int(Sensor2*100))

        Sensor0 = Sensor0[2:]
        Sensor1 = Sensor1[2:]
        #Sensor2 = Sensor2[2:]

        Sensor0_count_int = int(len(str(Sensor0)))
        Sensor1_count_int = int(len(str(Sensor1)))
        #Sensor2_count_int = int(len(str(Sensor2)))

        Sub0 = int(8 - Sensor0_count_int)
        Sub1 = int(8 - Sensor1_count_int)
        #Sub2 = int(8 - Sensor2_count_int)

        Sensor0_compl = (str(Sub0*"0")+Sensor0)
        Sensor1_compl = (str(Sub1*"0")+Sensor1)
        #Sensor2_compl = (str(Sub2*"0")+Sensor2)

        x = x+1
        print (">>>", x ,"<<<")
        print (Sensor0_compl)
        print (Sensor1_compl)
        #print (Sensor2_compl)


        #############################
    #    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    #    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    #    GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)

    #    GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.OUT)

    #    GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
    #    GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)
        #############################

        #Sensor0
    #    AgCh3A=(Sensor0_compl[0:1])
    #    if AgCh3A=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(4,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(4,False)

    #    AgPro2=(Sensor0_compl[1:2])
    #    if AgPro2=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(5,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(5,False)

    #    CharRo440=(Sensor0_compl[2:3])
    #    if CharRo440=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(6,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(6,False)

    #    AgInnoC=(Sensor0_compl[3:4])
    #    if AgInnoC=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(12,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(12,False)

    #    AgInnoB=(Sensor0_compl[4:5])
    #    if AgInnoB=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(13,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(13,False)

    #    ZK700=(Sensor0_compl[5:6])
    #    if ZK700=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(16,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(16,False)

    #    AgF3000=(Sensor0_compl[6:7])
    #    if AgF3000=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(17,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(17,False)

    #    ZK1200=(Sensor0_compl[7:8])
    #    if ZK1200=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(18,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(18,False)

        #Sensor1
    #    AgProV3=(Sensor1_compl[3:4])
    #    if AgProV3=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(19,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(19,False)

    #    MakWPG1=(Sensor1_compl[4:5])
    #    if MakWPG1=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(20,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(20,False)

    #    AgExcell2eC=(Sensor1_compl[5:6])
    #    if AgExcell2eC=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(21,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(21,False)

    #    AgCh2eC=(Sensor1_compl[6:7])
    #    if AgCh2eC=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(22,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(22,False)

    #    AgCh3B=(Sensor1_compl[7:8])
    #    if AgCh3B=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(23,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(23,False)
    #################################
    #    MM5=(Sensor1_compl[5:6])
    #    if MM5=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(24,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(24,False)

    #    MM6=(Sensor1_compl[6:7])
    #    if MM6=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(25,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(25,False)

    #    MM7=(Sensor2_compl[0:1])
    #    if MM7=="0":
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)


        #Sensor2
    #    MMM0=int(Sensor2[2:3])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM1=int(Sensor2[3:4])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #   MMM2=int(Sensor2[4:5])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM3=int(Sensor2[5:6])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #       GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM4=int(Sensor2[6:7])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM5=int(Sensor2[7:8])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM6=int(Sensor2[8:9])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)

    #    MMM7=int(Sensor2[9:10])
    #    if M0==1:
    #        GPIO.output(1,True)
    #    else:
    #        GPIO.output(1,False)


        #import time
        #time.sleep(1)

        #GPIO.cleanup()



def main():
    import time
    while True:
        try:
            core()
        except:
            continue
        time.sleep(0.01)



main()
```

Does somebody have an idea where my issue originates from?

Thank you

Comment: You have two `while True` statements in there, and nothing to break out of them (apart from an exception). Are you sure that when you restart it, the old one isn't still running your bottom `while True` every 10ms?

Comment: the truth is I cant tell. But you may be right.
So what is the correct way to terminate a script so that it does not keep running even though the python idle gui from where i executed the script has been closed?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the script isn't closing when you think it is. The obvious way to check for this is to see if `pythonw.exe` is still running in task manager.

To be really, really,sure  you could create a file in the 'continue' block of your `try/except`:

```
with open('filepath\file.txt','w') as myfile:
    pass
```

Then when you think you've killed the script, delete this file and see if it comes back. You'd have to increase your timeout to 1s or so to avoid flooding your system with file-creation requests as well.

Two thing to try first though:

- Get rid of the `while True` at the top of `core()`, it seems unnecessary
- Reduce the frequency of your calling loop, to, say once or twice a second

Comment: why should I get rid of the while true? 
I would like my programm to run continously, it has to run over the xml again from the start on to check if something has changed.

Or does a python script loop by itself without a while true or for condition?

Comment: Well, you've got two of them. One at the bottom, which will call `core()` every 100ms, and another within `core()` itself which will cause that loop to run continuously unless it hits an exception, Never-ending processor-intensive while loops are one cause of a system slow-down. I was suggesting it as a dubugging step, nothing more.

Comment: thany you, I totally missed that one! :-)

Comment: hi SiHa, something is theribly wrong! the xml what I am parsing is put into the network from a sensormeter (All4000). When I start my programm the unthinkable happens - the webserver of the device shuts down so that it is not pingable anymore. how can this be? this should be actually impossible! the singnal is gone completally. Do you have an Idea?
I was not able to debug yet with the tips you gave me due to that problem

Comment: I would guess that it might be because you're flooding it with requests (at 10 per second). What happens if you increase your `time.sleep()` to, say, 1s?

Comment: I need to try out that on monday, its the companys network. But thanks for your help